# Get Kerberos SPNs for a specific account programmatically

Tags: windows, winapi, kerberos

In my server application on Windows I try to register a kerberos SPN using the function DsServerRegisterSpn from NtDsAPI.

For the case this fails (because of missing access rights) I would like to check whether the SPN exists for my account (e.g. in case it manually had been created by an admin).
I need this information to decide whether I will offer kerberos authentication to clients and for logging purpose ("Kerberos not available: Please create SPN or give me right to register it myself")

I know that I can check it on the commandline with setSPN.exe -l  but I didn't find any way to get these information this programatically.

Is there an API function to achieve this?

Comment: According to [DsWriteAccountSpn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ntdsapi/nf-ntdsapi-dswriteaccountspnw#remarks), *SPNs passed to DsWriteAccountSpn are actually added to the Service-Principal-Name attribute of the computer object in pszAccount.* So you need [Accessing Attributes with ADSI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/accessing-attributes-with-adsi). The `DsWriteAccountSpn` document also explains the right about SPN.